# Hi,my application running fine manually when i run test in jmeter it sends 404 erros

Tags: jmeter

My application is running fine manually, when I run the test in JMeter it sends **404 errors** and I am getting the following error in the JMeter console window

```
uncaught exception java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror
c:\progfiles\java\jre\bin\jpeg.dll is not a valid win 32 applictaion
```

Comment: Please add the code causing this error to your question.

Comment: Is yourt java working?

Answer (score 0):

For Jemter Java above 1.6 is required, refer prerequisotes http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html.

Jmeter is a Java application, so a JRE or SDK first needs to be installed with a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Then find the `jmeter.bat` file and add following lines at top:

```
set JAVA_HOME=c:\Java -- the java installation folder
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH
```

Comment: java working fine.its a simple php application installed in xampp and it sending error in jmeter log as html link parse error and sometimes it is throwing error as undefinedlinkerror

Comment: @surajan Could you close (delete) that question in that case?